# Proportional percentage increases in groups

Tags: percentages

If I have 4 gases in an atmosphere, lets say:

- A makes up 78%
- B makes up 21%
- C makes up .93%
- D makes up .04%

If the percentage of gas D increases to 5%, how do I find the proportional percentage decrease in the others?

*The actual question is if given that the others decrease proportionally, is if the atmosphere is molecularly heavier

A being Nitrogen, B being Oxygen, C being Argon, D being CO2

Comment: Increases *to* 5% or *by* 5%? I just want to clarify.

Comment: There seems to be some information missing.  Why does the percentage of D increase?  Perhaps the percentage of A drops to $73\%$  Or perhaps the percentage of B drops to $16\%$

Comment: increases TO 5%.  So new percentage of D in atmosphere is 5% . +4.96%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 0.04% to 5.00% we added 4.96%.

So the other components must be decreased proportionally by (99.96-4.96)/99.96 = 95.00/99.96.

Where 99.96 = 100 - 0.04.

--

```
A - NITROGEN

INITIAL = 78%

FINAL = 78% (99.96-4.96)/99.96 = 74.129652%
```

--

```
B - OXYGEN

INITIAL = 21%

FINAL = 21% (99.96-4.96)/99.96 = 19.957983%
```

--

```
C - ARGON

INITIAL = 0.93%

FINAL = 0.93% (99.96-4.96)/99.96 = 0.883854%
```

--

```
D - CO2

INITIAL = 0.04%

FINAL = 5.00000 % (Increase 4.96%)
```

--

```
E - OTHERS

INITIAL = 0.03%

FINAL = 0.03% (99.96-4.96)/99.96 = 0.028511%
```

--